# Definição de container e component em swing

Tags: java, swing, gui

Quais são as definições precisas de Container e Component no Swing? Porque esses elementos são importantes para a construção da GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Container é um Component](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/images/swing_class_hierarchy.jpg) que disponibiliza espaço para que você inclua outros componentes, inclusive outros containers.

É comum que se trate de container como tela e component como objetos a serem utilizados nela, tipo botões, labels e etc.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_containers.htm.

O fato de eles serem importantes se dá básicamente porque eles são a essência de tudo o que você possa fazer em uma aplicação swing.